# Recommended ways to implement MVVM View Model populating and Store updating with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to learn WPF and I have basic questions about implementing MVVM and Entity Framework that I can't find answered online. Examples and tutorials I have found either address a related but different question or are over my head.

I want to build a very simple CRUD one-to-many application, say Customers and Orders, to understand MVVM with Entity Framework 6 at a basic level. I don't understand how to implement the View Model correctly.

Say the generated entities navigation properties are ObservableCollections. 
Entity Framework generates a `Customer` class and an `Order` class. The `Customer` class contains a virtual collection property `Orders`, of type `ObservableCollection<Order>`.

Should the View Model contain properties:
`ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers` to be a binding source for a customers ComboBox or ListView or DataGrid `ItemsSource`;
`SelectedCustomer` of type `Customer` for binding to that control's `SelectedItem` property;
`ObservableCollection<Order> Orders` to be another `ItemsSource` binding;
`SelectedOrder` to be the `SelectedItem` binding for creating/editing/deleting orders?

If so, how should I populate the `Orders` bound collection with order lines for a customer?

What is the recommended way to update the Store? Is it: the Add Order command in the View Model adds an `Order` object to the View Model's `Orders` collection, then the Save command adds the same object to the `DbSet` in the `DbContext`, and similarly for Delete, before executing `SaveChanges()` on the `DBContext`?

Comment: You should not use Entities for binding instead you should use `Model` for binding. That is the correct way. Also you should choose some MVVM framework like MVVM Light or Prism that I use in most of the project. Use link `http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel` to learn how to implement MVVM light in your project.

Comment: To clarify: I bind to the properties in the View Model that I have mentioned above. I want to understand this at the most basic level, without using additional frameworks.

Comment: So in that case can you post your sample code?

Comment: You should build a simplified prototype and see how things go. These kinds of tasks typically work themselves out in a straightforward way.

Comment: @Will I appreciate what you say. I am asking this question because I don't want to start basing my understanding of View Model implementation with EF on ways that more experienced programmers reject as flawed at their root.

Comment: There are tons of different ways to handle this. There isn't any one right way, and no way that is seen as "flawed".  Other than using PHP.